# Adjust the indentation whithin the algorithmicx-package when a line is broken

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, algorithms, algorithmicx

I have this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
   \caption{Minimal Working Example for my Problem}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
   \While{Indentation is a mess}
      \State Examine a very long line that looks horrible because the indentation is all messed up.
   \EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}​
```

I would want the broken text to be indented to the same column, where the statement began.

Comment: This is fixed in the forked [algpseudocode**x**](https://ctan.org/pkg/algpseudocodex) package.

Answer (score 18):

Wrap your long line in a `t`op-aligned `\parbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Minimal Working Example for my Problem}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \While{Indentation is a mess}
      \State \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\algorithmicindent}{Examine a very long line that looks horrible 
        because the indentation is all messed up.\strut}
    \EndWhile
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}​
```

The current indentation (`\algorithmicindent`) is removed from `\linewidth` to fit exactly within the horizontal line width. Adding a `\strut` at the end allows for proper vertical alignment between lines (or `\State`s) in lines that have no descenders.

Comment: Thanks. Works well. Is there a way to make this the default behaviour?

Comment: @Tom: I'll have to look at the source code and see. I'll get back to you if I find anything.

Comment: @Tom: I'm sure this is possible, but it would be difficult. One would have to capture the content - not easily done - and pass it to `\parbox`.

Comment: @Werner I realize it's been some time since you wrote this answer but implementing it is causing my text to go slightly past the right margin for some reason. Do you have any idea why this would be?

Comment: @SamuelYusim: So you're getting an "overfull `\hbox` warning"? You probably are deeper into the nesting than in my example, right? You could use a manual `1.5em` (1st level), `3em` (2nd level), `4.5em` (3rd level) ... rather than `\algorithmicindent`. The reason is that `\algorithmicindent` is not a length, but a macro. If this doesn't help, could you post some code I can look at (at [Pastebin](http://pastebin.org)).

Comment: @Werner that solved the problem perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: For the reference of others, here is a macro ready to use for you: `\newcommand{\algparbox}[1]{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\algorithmicindent}{#1\strut}}`.

Comment: Here is a macro I made that works for multi-level indentation. The first parameter is the number of levels of indentation required for that line.

`\newcommand*{\LongState}[2]{\State\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\dimexpr\algorithmicindent*#1}{#2\strut}}`