# How to automatically keep the indentation level when a line has to be broken

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, algorithms, algorithmicx

I'm using the `algpseudocode` package with two custom commands, `\Let` and `\LongState` to handle automatic indentation of (broken) long lines in the spirit of [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68540/34574), which uses `\parbox` to wrap the long line's content.

However, the following approach does not work well when the indentation level is more than one. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{calc}

% A command for defining assignments within the algorithmic environment which
% supports automatic indentation when the second argument is too long to fit
% on one line
\newcommand*{\Let}[2]{\State #1 $\gets$
\parbox[t]{\linewidth-\algorithmicindent-\widthof{ #1 $\gets$}}{#2\strut}}
% A \State command that supports automatic indentation when the argument's
% content is too long to fit on one line
\newcommand*{\LongState}[1]{\State
\parbox[t]{\linewidth-\algorithmicindent}{#1\strut}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{This is some testing pseudo-code showing what happens with nested long
lines}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Function{test}{$(x, y)$}
    \Let{$a$}{some math expression}
    \Let{$b$}{some very very long expression that doesn't fit on one line and is
    even longer and longer}
    \For{each $e$ in a list}
        \Let{$l(e)$}{the length of element $e$}
        \If{some condition on $l(e)$}
            \LongState{run some complex sub-routine and get the result and this
            description is very very long, long indeed...}
            \Let{$a$}{some math expression}
            \Let{$b$}{some very very long expression that doesn't fit on one
            line and is even longer and longer}
            \If{some other condition}
                \Let{$c$}{another math expression}
            \EndIf
        \EndIf
    \EndFor
  \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The following renders as:
[image]

Line 3 is an example of a well broken long line, whereas lines 7 and 9 stretch out too far.

**Edit:** I initially encountered this problem when writing my PhD Thesis using the [cam-thesis](https://github.com/cambridge/thesis/) class and XeLaTeX. My setup is Fedora 17 with TeXLive 2013 as packaged by [Jindrich Novy](http://jnovy.fedorapeople.org/texlive/2012/packages.f17/).

If I use [Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130212/34574) and change the document's class to `\documentclass{cam-thesis}` (following is a MWE):

```
\documentclass{cam-thesis}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{linegoal}

% A command for defining assignments within the algorithmic environment which
% supports automatic indentation when the second argument is too long to fit
% on one line
\newcommand*{\Let}[2]{\State #1 $\gets$
\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{#2\strut}}
% A \State command that supports automatic indentation when the argument's
% content is too long to fit on one line
\newcommand*{\LongState}[1]{\State
\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{#1\strut}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{This is some testing pseudo-code showing what happens with nested long
lines}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Function{test}{$(x, y)$}
    \Let{$a$}{some math expression}
    \Let{$b$}{some very very long expression that doesn't fit on one line and is
    even longer and longer}
    \For{each $e$ in a list}
        \Let{$l(e)$}{the length of element $e$}
        \If{some condition on $l(e)$}
            \LongState{run some complex sub-routine and get the result and this
            description is very very long, long indeed...}
            \Let{$a$}{some math expression}
            \Let{$b$}{some very very long expression that doesn't fit on one
            line and is even longer and longer}
            \If{some other condition}
                \Let{$c$}{another math expression}
            \EndIf
        \EndIf
    \EndFor
  \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I get the following (`cam-thesis` with `XeLaTeX`):
[image]

Debugging this further, however, I found that the following combinations work:

1. `cam-thesis` with `pdfLaTeX`:
   [image]
2. `article` with `XeLaTeX`:
   [image]
3. `article` with `pdfLaTeX`:
   [image]

All three of the above options work fine, but I really need to use `cam-thesis` with `XeLaTeX`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use `\linegoal` (from the [`linegoal`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/linegoal) package) as the width of the `\parbox`es; `\linegoal` expands to the dimension of the remainder of the line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{linegoal}

% A command for defining assignments within the algorithmic environment which
% supports automatic indentation when the second argument is too long to fit
% on one line
\newcommand*{\Let}[2]{\State #1 $\gets$
\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{#2\strut}}
% A \State command that supports automatic indentation when the argument's
% content is too long to fit on one line
\newcommand*{\LongState}[1]{\State
\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{#1\strut}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{This is some testing pseudo-code showing what happens with nested long
lines}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Function{test}{$(x, y)$}
    \Let{$a$}{some math expression}
    \Let{$b$}{some very very long expression that doesn't fit on one line and is
    even longer and longer}
    \For{each $e$ in a list}
        \Let{$l(e)$}{the length of element $e$}
        \If{some condition on $l(e)$}
            \LongState{run some complex sub-routine and get the result and this
            description is very very long, long indeed...}
            \Let{$a$}{some math expression}
            \Let{$b$}{some very very long expression that doesn't fit on one
            line and is even longer and longer}
            \If{some other condition}
                \Let{$c$}{another math expression}
            \EndIf
        \EndIf
    \EndFor
  \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Addendum

With XeLaTeX and the `cam-thesis` document class (link to the class appears in the question) used by **tjanez**, there's a problem with `\linegoal`; the problem doesn't appear with the standard classes (see edit to the question). A quick work-around is to use a shorter value:

```
\documentclass{cam-thesis}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{linegoal}

% A command for defining assignments within the algorithmic environment which
% supports automatic indentation when the second argument is too long to fit
% on one line
\newcommand*{\Let}[2]{\State #1 $\gets$
\parbox[t]{-52,29pt+\linegoal}{#2\strut}}
% A \State command that supports automatic indentation when the argument's
% content is too long to fit on one line
\newcommand*{\LongState}[1]{\State
\parbox[t]{-52,29pt+\linegoal}{#1\strut}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{This is some testing pseudo-code showing what happens with nested long
lines}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Function{test}{$(x, y)$}
    \Let{$a$}{some math expression}
    \Let{$b$}{some very very long expression that doesn't fit on one line and is
    even longer and longer}
    \For{each $e$ in a list}
        \Let{$l(e)$}{the length of element $e$}
        \If{some condition on $l(e)$}
            \LongState{run some complex sub-routine and get the result and this
            description is very very long, long indeed...}
            \Let{$a$}{some math expression}
            \If{some condition on $l(e)$}
            \Let{$b$}{some very very long expression that doesn't fit on one
            line and is even longer and longer}
            \If{some other condition}
                \Let{$c$}{another math expression}
              \EndIf
            \EndIf
        \EndIf
    \EndFor
  \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I suggest you to get in touch with the author/maintainer of `cam-thesis` to comment this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I still have an issue. I'm using the [cam-thesis](https://raw.github.com/cambridge/thesis/master/cam-thesis.cls) class and when used with `\documentclass{cam-thesis}` your solution doesn't work. I'm new on TeX.SX and I don't know whether I should accept your answer and post a new question or resolve it all in one question?

Comment: @tjanez I just did a test, using the exact same code I posted but changing article to cam-thesis and everything worked as expected, so the problem must be elsewhere. At this point I would suggest you to produce a minimal document with your current settings and allowing us to reproduce the problem; edit your question, and add this minimal document there. Leave a comment here so I get notified. By the way, you should have  mentioned that you were using some other class from the beginning.

Comment: I apologize for not giving the full details in the beginning. The document I was writing is my PhD Thesis and it is way too complicated to post it all here, so I trimmed it down to a MWE. I just discovered that probably the reason it works for you with `cam-thesis` class is that you are using `pdfLaTeX`, whereas I use `XeLaTeX`. I edited the question and gave full details of my setup.

Comment: @tjanez thank you for providing the additional information. You're right, my code works using cam-thesis with pdfLaTeX, but not with XeLaTeX; in fact, XeLaTeX and `linegoal` seem not to like each other. I'll let you know if I can think of a solution for this case.

Comment: @tjanez A possible workaround: `\newcommand*{\Let}[2]{\State #1 $\gets$
\parbox[t]{-52,29pt+\linegoal}{#2\strut}}
\newcommand*{\LongState}[1]{\State
\parbox[t]{-52,29pt+\linegoal}{#1\strut}}`. This will work, but you'll get a warning about labels.

Comment: I checked and the work-around works. However, I still have a small issue with it: `Latexmk` gives me this error: "Did not finish processing file 'thesis': 'pdflatex' needed too many passes Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing, unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex." I can live with that but it would be nice if it could be fixed.

Comment: It seems you've lost the "end for" and "end if" part also... do you have a remedy for this? Many thanks,
J

Comment: @JakeTaylor-King that's because `algpseudocode` was loaded by the OP with the `noend` option. Remove the option.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the previous LongState command with this worked for me with journal and pdflatex.

All the best.

```
\newcommand*{\LongState}[1]{\State
\parbox[t]{\linewidth-\algorithmicindent-\algorithmicindent}{#1\strut}}
```

Comment: This is rather a comment than a answer.